# How to access FlowNode in typescript ast api?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, typescript-compiler-api, ts-morph

I try to resolve `foo` and `bar` from `nodes` variable.

After I checked at ts-ast-viewer you can see in the picture that typescript can know about `foo` and `bar` from `nodes` node, under FlowNode section. (node -> initializer -> elements -> escapedText (foo, bar)).

But how I can access FlowNode?

I using `ts-morph` to work on my typescript ast code. and I already have the `nodes` Identifier. unfortunately I can't access to the properties I can see in the FlowNode section:

```
console.log({ n: nodes.node }); //<-- node not exist in nodes but I can see this in picture.
```

The full code:

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-elion-hlll9d?file=/src/index.ts)

```
import { Project, SyntaxKind } from "ts-morph";

console.clear();

const project = new Project({
  skipAddingFilesFromTsConfig: true
});

const sourceFile = project.createSourceFile(
  "foo.ts",
  `
const items = [foo, bar];
const nodes = [...items];
  `
);

const nodes = sourceFile
  .getDescendantsOfKind(SyntaxKind.Identifier)
  .find((n) => n.getText() === "nodes");

console.log({ n: nodes.node.initializer }); // <-- error: node is undefined
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flow nodes aren't exposed in ts-morph at the moment and aren't actually really exposed in the compiler API's type declarations, but you can still access them.

```
import { Project, ts } from "ts-morph";

console.clear();

const project = new Project({
  skipAddingFilesFromTsConfig: true
});

const sourceFile = project.createSourceFile(
  "foo.ts",
  `
const items = [foo, bar];
const nodes = [...items];
  `
);

// get the identifier
const nodesIdent = sourceFile
  .getVariableDeclarationOrThrow("nodes")
  .getNameNode();

// hack to force the type checker to create the flow node
nodesIdent.getType();

// get the flow node
const flowNode = (nodesIdent.compilerNode as any).flowNode as ts.FlowNode;

console.log({ n: flowNode });
```

I've opened https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph/issues/1276 to make this easier for the future.